# Как сделать скрытие колонок в Datatables?

Tags: javascript, html, datatable

Как воспользоваться данной функцией DataTables: https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/column_visibility/stateSave.html ? Я делал всё, что мог, перечитал всю документацию, но она не работает. Помогите пожалуйста!

```
$("#table").dataTable({
                    responsive: true,
            colReorder: true,
                    language: {
                        "processing": "Подождите...",
                        "search": "Поиск:",
                        "lengthMenu": " _MENU_ ",
                        "info": "Показано с _START_ до _END_ записей из _TOTAL_",
                        "infoEmpty": "Записи с 0 до 0 из 0 записей",
                        "infoFiltered": "(отфильтровано из _MAX_ записей)",
                        "infoPostFix": "",
                        "loadingRecords": "Загрузка записей...",
                        "zeroRecords": "Записи отсутствуют.",
                        "emptyTable": "В таблице отсутствуют данные",
                        "paginate": {
                        "first": "Первая",
                        "previous": "<",
                        "next": ">",
                        "last": "Последняя"
                        },
                        "aria": {
                        "sortAscending": ": активировать для сортировки столбца по возрастанию",
                        "sortDescending": ": активировать для сортировки столбца по убыванию"
                        }
                    },
                    "iDisplayLength": 10,
                    "aLengthMenu": [[ 3, 10, 20, 50, 100 ,-1],[ 3, 10,20,50,100,"все"]],
                    stateSave: true,
            dom: 'Bfrtip',
            stateSave: true,
            buttons: [
                'colvis'
            ]
        });
```

Comment: Прицепите сниппет на котором воспроизводится проблема

Comment: То есть таблицу или весь html?

Comment: Соберите через "фрагмент кода", думаю, одной таблицы будет достаточно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все прекрасно работает, можно проверить тут:

```
$("#table").dataTable({
                responsive: true,
        colReorder: true,
                language: {
                    "processing": "Подождите...",
                    "search": "Поиск:",
                    "lengthMenu": " _MENU_ ",
                    "info": "Показано с _START_ до _END_ записей из _TOTAL_",
                    "infoEmpty": "Записи с 0 до 0 из 0 записей",
                    "infoFiltered": "(отфильтровано из _MAX_ записей)",
                    "infoPostFix": "",
                    "loadingRecords": "Загрузка записей...",
                    "zeroRecords": "Записи отсутствуют.",
                    "emptyTable": "В таблице отсутствуют данные",
                    "paginate": {
                    "first": "Первая",
                    "previous": "<",
                    "next": ">",
                    "last": "Последняя"
                    },
                    "aria": {
                    "sortAscending": ": активировать для сортировки столбца по возрастанию",
                    "sortDescending": ": активировать для сортировки столбца по убыванию"
                    }
                },
                "iDisplayLength": 10,
                "aLengthMenu": [[ 3, 10, 20, 50, 100 ,-1],[ 3, 10,20,50,100,"все"]],
                dom: 'Bfrtip',

        stateSave: true,
        buttons: [
        'colvis'
    ]
    });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/74wm9oxj/5/

Важно!
Проверьте внимательно, что ВСЕ перечисленное у вас подключено
https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js (сам jQuery)
https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js (datatables)
https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.1/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js (расширение buttons)
https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.1/js/buttons.colVis.min.js (расширение видимости столбцов)

Comment: все ссылки и вообще всё тоже самое было, но почему-то не работало. Спасибо. А как убрать определённую колонку из списка, что бы её не возможно было скрыть?

Comment: Как вариант - после инициализации таблицы, найти этот сгенерированный элемент и скрыть тот, который не нужен. Но я делал сокрытие конкретных столбцов через column().visible() ( https://datatables.net/reference/api/column().visible() )
Там просто указываешь какую колонку (или колонки) скрыть/показать.